# JQuery Event Not Firing First Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there's a couple of similar issues, but none of them seem to work in my case.

I have this JQuery code snip:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  CartCount();

  $('.product-item input[type="submit"]').on('click', CartCount);

});

function CartCount() {
  var cartItems = 0;
  var cartItemTypes = iGetCookie("NumberOrdered", 0);
  var cartItem;
  for(i = 1; i <= cartItemTypes; i++) {
    cartItem = String(GetCookie("Order." + i)).split("|");
    cartItems += parseInt(cartItem[1]);
  }
  $('.top-cart-count').html(cartItems);
}
```

The code works perfectly after the second click but never the first. After the second click, .top-cart-count displays the cartItems value that should have been displayed on the previous click. Any ideas?

Edit: Sorry if I wasn't very clear about what's going on. I actually have multiple cookies: 1 for the sum of all the different types of items the user orders and 1 for each item type. Within the cookie for each individual type is an array which contains the quantity (just of that type) at index 1. CardCount() basically just sums up all the quantities for all the different types if there are any items ordered (at least 1 type). Basically, I'm trying to update the item count AND display this updated count when the form is submitted. Since the cookie that stores number of different types is set to 0 by default, I don't think I need to call the add function before the display (unless I'm updating the value).

My HTML:

```
<form onSubmit="return AddToCart(this)">
        <input type="submit"  value="Add to Cart">
      </form>
```

Comment: Why are you calling CartCount(); at load when it's already a callback ?

Comment: @zer00ne .top-cart-count is set to 0 by default while cartItems is actually a cookie value. I want to display cartItems on load and update the count on click.

Comment: OK, I can't duplicate your code perfectly since I don't have any examples of the actual data like cookies or the HTML, but it's a functioning Demo never the less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@wow and @zerrone are correct about the problem being caused by something else (another function running asynchronously). I was updating *cartItems* when the form *.product-item input[type="submit"]* belongs to was submitted. At the same time, when the input was clicked, I was trying to display the updated value. For some reason, the display function (*CartCount*) was getting called before the update function (*AddToCart*).

I added changed the code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  CartCount();

});

function updateCart(form) {
  AddToCart(form);
  CartCount();
}

function CartCount() {
  var cartItems = 0;
  var cartItemTypes = iGetCookie("NumberOrdered", 0);
  var cartItem;
  for(i = 1; i <= cartItemTypes; i++) {
    cartItem = String(GetCookie("Order." + i)).split("|");
    cartItems += parseInt(cartItem[1]);
  }
  $('.top-cart-count').html(cartItems);
}
```

In my html, I call *updateCart* like this: `<form onSubmit="return updateCart(this)">`

Thanks for the help all!

Comment: *"For some reason, the display function (CartCount) was getting called before the update function (AddToCart)"* Yes, it gets called at load time even before it's bound to the click event. See my answer.